# Does the Laplacian of any scalar gravitational field vanish outside the source?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Besides the common spherical symmetric gravitational field, there are 2 classical examples: infinite plane and infinite wire.

For spherical symmetrical and infinite plane, the Laplacian of the field is zero (outside the source).

But for the infinite wire, while I manage to get the correct gradient (acceleration inverse proportional to r) the Laplacian doesn't vanish. Where is my mistake?

$$\begin{align}
\phi &= -GM\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}) \\
\nabla \phi &= -GM\frac{(x,y,z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \\
\nabla^2\phi &= -GM\left[-\frac{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} + \frac{3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right] = -\frac{GM}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an *infinite wire* the potential should not depend on one of coordinates, e.g. $z$, assuming that the wire correspond to $(x=0,\,y=0)$ line:
$$ \phi = -GM\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).$$